# AppleScript - Advanced functions to improve steps / reduce code

Tags: macos, command-line, applescript, quicktime

I'm trying to reduce the number of steps and and increase performance for my applescript, I just wondered if there are some common functions I can employ.

Here's an example script...

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate

    -- Get the iCloud file path to avoid permission error
    set filePath to "Macintosh HD:Users:jm:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~QuickTimePlayerX:Documents:movie.wav"

    set f to a reference to file filePath
    -- Get a handle to the initial window
    set windowID to id of first window whose name = "Audio Recording"
    set audio to first document whose name = (get name of first window whose id = windowID)

    tell audio
        stop
    end tell
    -- Get second handle to new titled window
    set windowID2 to id of first window whose name = "Untitled"
    set audio2 to first document whose name = (get name of first window whose id = windowID2)

    tell audio2
        -- Save audio file
        save audio2 in f
    end tell

    -- Get third handle to new titled window
    set windowID3 to id of first window whose name = "movie.wav.qtpxcomposition"
    set audio3 to first document whose name = (get name of first window whose id = windowID3)
    tell audio3
        close audio3 saving no
    end tell


end tell
```

This is the second script, called after a script which starts recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reduce your script to this:

```
    tell application "QuickTime Player"
        -- Get the iCloud file path to avoid permission error
        set filePath to "Macintosh HD:Users:jm:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~QuickTimePlayerX:Documents:movie.wav"

        -- Get a handle to the initial window
        stop the document named "Audio Recording"

        -- Get second handle to new titled window
        save the document named "Untitled" in filePath

        -- Get third handle to new titled window
        close the document named "movie.wav.qtpxcomposition" saving no
    end tell
```

As I mentioned in my comment, it's redundant to retrieve a window's `id` by its `name`, only then to retrieve its `name` from that `id`.  You can reference the `document` by the name you already have (if no document by that name exists, it will throw an error; but the same is also true of your original script).  To avoid this, you could check it exists first:

```
    tell document named "Audio Recording" to if it exists then stop
```

The `activate` command seemed unnecessary, as none of the commands that followed require *QuickTime* to be in focus.

Finally, the variable `f` was redundant.

#### EDIT

<sup>Added on `2019-11-07`

**Re:** first comment below by OP

**Summary:** References document through its window's `id` rather than by `name` for increased robustness.</sup>

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    set filePath to "Macintosh HD:Users:jm:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~QuickTimePlayerX:Documents:movie.wav"

    set windowID to the id of window 1 where the name of its document is "Audio Recording"
    tell the document of window id windowID
        stop
        save in filePath
        close
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: The `close the document named "movie.wav.qtpxcomposition" saving no` no longer works, on Mojave it show a `Finishing Recording..` dialog which never finishes... Any ideas?

Comment: I don't use Mojave, but reviewing the script now, I think references by name to a document whose name keeps changing is fragile. The `id` should remain constant, in theory, so we can grab it once and use it exclusively. So similar in approach to your original script, but just one-third of it. I'll add an edit to the answer, but it's a shot in the dark as to whether it will change the situation. If you uploaded a photo to Imgur with a screenshot cropped to show the entire contents of _Script Editor_'s `Replies` pane up to where you terminate the script, it might enlighten.

Comment: Thanks, the `Replies` panel doesn't show anything additional. However I've just found `quit` which seems to work.

Comment: Ok, well done. 